# Why doesn't 'sudo bash && cd desktop' cd in to the desktop folder?

Tags: bash, shell, sudo, cd-command

I have a folder with `chmod 000` permissions on it with a lot of different stuff in, the way I get in is a start `bash` in `sudo` by running `sudo bash`.

Why can't I do `&&`? I want to `cd` into the directory with one command like this:

```
sudo bash && cd desktop
```

When I run this, I am still in `~` which is the default directory.

I have to run this instead

```
sudo bash
cd desktop
```

Also, the desktop is not the folder, its a subfolder of desktop, but it doesn't matter. It's the same thing anyways.

Comment: Why have the permissions set to 000 tho?

Comment: @jasonwryan No, this is not a duplicate (at least not of this question). That question doesn't really help to understand DisplayName's issue, and it definitely doesn't fully answer it.

Comment: Neither of these "possible duplicate" nominations is correct.

Answer (score 18):

The part after `&&` is executed in the current shell, it is not some argument handed over to the `bash` you run with `sudo`.

You might be tempted to try

```
sudo bash -c 'cd desktop'
```

but that doesn't work because that `bash` exits after `cd desktop`.

You can try:

```
sudo sh -c 'cd desktop && exec bash'
```

which "works" (i.e. places you in the directory `desktop` in a Bash shell with uid=0). I'd rather issue the two separate commands than that one liner.

Comment: Your answer is 100% correct, except you (IMHO) miss the point of the OP’s confusion. I believe the key point of the answer to this question is that `sudo bash` runs the privileged shell *in a new, separate process*, and that the “current” (primary) shell doesn’t handle the `cd` command until the (secondary) privileged shell exits. I suspect that the OP is looking at `sudo bash && cd desktop` as if it were analogous to `set -x && cd desktop`.

Answer (score 2):

It does work, just not how you expect. `&&` waits until the command before it completes. If the result at that point is `true`, it will execute the next instruction. So if you type `bash && cd desktop`, you will first be presented with a bash shell. If you type `exit`, you'll be back in whatever shell you were in before, and *then* the directory will change to the desktop folder.

In terms of the functionality I described, sudo is inconsequential. Your use case for sudo is probably not best practice, and you should consider other solutions.